# Vue.JS - how to use localStorage with Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage, vue.js

I am working on Markdown editor with Vue.JS, and I tried to use localStorage with it to save data but I don't know how to save new value to data variables in Vue.JS whenever the user types!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I found the solution that I was looking for. first use watch method to detect changes on variable you are storing data on like this:

```
watch: {
  input: function () {
    if (isLocalStorage() /* function to detect if localstorage is supported*/) {
      localStorage.setItem('storedData', this.input)
    }
  }
}
```

This will update variable’s value whenever user add new inputs.

Then assign the new value to variable like this:

```
app.input = localStorage.getItem('storedData');
```

And that's it :)

Answer (score 64):

You can just do following to save in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
localStorage.setItem('YourItem', response.data)
```

You can fetch this using:

```
localStorage.getItem('YourItem')
```

To delete this from `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.removeItem('YourItem')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use the local storage in Vue:

To store:

```
localStorage.storedData = this.input;
```

To get the data:

```
let value = localStorage.storedData;
```

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html

Comment: actually this answer worked for me but accepted answer did not work

Answer (score 2):

you can use v-model to bind you variable with every change or you can put it computed :{} section.computed is like life hook of vue.js it re-render the component again when it values are changed.