# Data from Vuex storage are not displayed in the vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2, vuex

The Vuex storage has a getter which returns object by id.
But I can't use the data from the getter.

When i use computed: data come from getter after the component was rendered, and DOM still empty (until I'm not clicking on component in vue devtools. If i click, computed run again, and element are redrawn and filled with the data from data())

if I call the getter directly during the definition of data() objects, `{{ cardData.content }}` in DOM can be seen immediately, but `this.cardData.title` returns an error `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. Why?

Vuex storage

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        "cards": [
            {
                "position": null,
                "title": "Head Text",
                "id": 132,
                "content": "LoremIpsum",
                "type": "text",
            },
            {
                "position": null,
                "title": "Head Text 2",
                "id": 138,
                "content": "LoremIpsumLoremIpsum",
                "type": "text",
            }
        ]
    },

    getters: {
        cards: (state) => state.cards
    }
});
```

vue component,

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>{{ cardTitle }}{{ cardTitle2 }}</h1>
  <div>{{ cardData.content }}</div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    props: ['id'],
    data() {
      return {
        cardData: this.$store.getters.cards.find((card) => card.id == this.id),
        cardTitle: this.cardData.title,
        cardData2: null,
        cardTitle2: null
      }
    },
    computed: {
      GetData: function() {
        this.cardData2 = this.$store.getters.cards.find((card) => card.id == this.current);
        this.cardTitle2 = this.cardData2.title;
      },
    } 
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just have a computed property which returns desired title, it can be just following as documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties):

```
computed: {
  cardTitle: function() {
   var card = this.$store.getters.cards.find((card) => card.id == this.current)
   return card.title
  },
}
```

Now you can use `{{this.cardTitle}}` in the DOM.

Comment: Works great, thanks! 
Could you explain why if I call a method in the template, it returns the correct value, but if in data() I get undefined

Comment: In vue, data is just initialised in the data block, It does not track all the changes in `id` or `vuex` store later like computed property do, so it will take just the value at time of initialising the vue instance.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Maybe you know some way to get untracked data from storage? This would be useful in some cases where the data from storage need in another object in the component, like google chart

Comment: You looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425889/vue-js-how-to-use-localstorage-with-vue-js/41426058#41426058)?

Comment: I put in the LocalStorage object card (from getter), and when pulled it out it turned out here that:

`function boundFn(a) { var l = arguments.length; return l ? l > 1 ? fn.apply(ctx, arguments) : fn.call(ctx, a) : fn.call(ctx) }`

Comment: Sorry could not understand it, I will recommend to write a separate question here with all the details and errors if any.

Answer (score 1):

**Getting Vuex State into Vue Components**

> So how do we display state inside the store in our Vue components?
>   Since Vuex stores are reactive, the simplest way to "retrieve" state
>   from it is simply returning some store state from within a computed
>   property

In your case you have card array in vuex state, and you use data method to return array. That is not proper way to handle this case. You need to use **computed method** as a getter. Whenever `this.$store.state.card` changes, it will cause the computed property to re-evaluate, and trigger associated DOM updates:

```
 computed: {
    cardData() {
      return this.$store.getters.cards
    }
  }
```

And in your component template you can display properties from cardData array, whether it needs to be title, content, type, id...etc. You don't need to create cardTitle, cardId, cardType variables for every property in array, just add property after cardData:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
  <h1>{{ cardData.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ cardData.content }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/908mqetp/6/) example for your case, filtered cardData array by id.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help! 
it works on jsfiddle, but in my app that way returns `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. I don't know why, maybe the exported *.vue elements behave a little differently, or the reason is that in a real application multiple elements nested within each other. I need to do a couple of experimentation to say probably

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient if you loop through the array using v-for as indicated in the [vue.js documentation homepage.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

```
computed: {
     cards () {
          return this.$store.getters.cardData
     }
}
```

this.$store.getters.cardData in computed being what you have initialised in getters: i.e

```
getters: {
    cardData: (state) => state.cards
}
```

and state like so:

```
state: {
    cards: []
}
```

then in your template tag, you can loop through the dataset array like so:

```
<template id="insert id here">
    <ul v-for"card in cards" :key="card.id">
       <li> {{ card.title }}</li>
       <li> {{ card.content }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```