# How do I add localstorage to my to-do vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make a to-do app, but I do not know how should I make the local storage with Vue.
My App.vue looks like this:

[App.vue code photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLoU8.jpg)

[App.vue code photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZqPo.jpg)

This code here is from TodoList.vue for deleting and completing a task. And I have two more components that are for editing task and posting new task. Maybe the localstorage method should be in CreatingTodo.vue ? I installed *npm install vue-localstorage --save* but from now I do not know where and how to continue with the storage.

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <p class="tasks">Completed Tasks: {{todos.filter(todo => {return todo.done === true}).length}}</p>
    <p class="tasks">Pending Tasks: {{todos.filter(todo => {return todo.done === false}).length}}</p>
    <todo v-on:delete-todo="deleteTodo" v-on:complete-todo="completeTodo" v-for="todo in todos" :todo.sync="todo"></todo>
  </div>
</template>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
import sweetalert from 'sweetalert';
import Todo from './Todo';

export default {
  props: ['todos'],
  components: {
    Todo,
  },
  methods: {
    deleteTodo(todo) {
      sweetalert({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'This To-Do will be permanently deleted!',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        closeOnConfirm: false,
      },
      () => {
        const todoIndex = this.todos.indexOf(todo);
        this.todos.splice(todoIndex, 1);
        sweetalert('Deleted!', 'Your To-Do has been deleted.', 'success');
      });
    },
    completeTodo(todo) {
      const todoIndex = this.todos.indexOf(todo);
      this.todos[todoIndex].done = true;
      sweetalert('Success!', 'To-Do completed!', 'success');
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
p.tasks {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

My second question is also regarding Vue. Because until now I was writing my University project on HTML,CSS and JavaScript. How can I connect both projects this todo is localhost:8080 and the other part of the project is just local path.Thank you in advance!

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.JS - how to use localstorage with Vue.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425889/vue-js-how-to-use-localstorage-with-vue-js)

Comment: Please search before posting a new question :) Also, please ask one question per post. Hint: your second question has probably already been answered in another post.

Comment: @Boaz , thank you very much. I will keep it in mind for the future. I apologize :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the [vue-ls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-ls) package in all of my projects for local storage access and it is really easy to use.

On the the other hand, you could just access the local storage directly with the [native JavaScript APIs for LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

This is not that easy to implement with one line or two lines of code with your current implementation.

I noticed you're...

- not sing vuex
- passing list as a prop
- modifying(mutating) the prop

Using vuex moved the data into a separate global store, where data can be accessed and changes can be made from any component, without the need to pass data from parent.There's a nit of a learning curve when getting started with it, but you may find it helpful. It also allows easily adding a local storage implementation after any mutation through a few lines of code, or use of a library.

The problem with passing a prop is that if the data changes in the parent, the change is pushed to the child, effectively destroying your modified version. This would require the component owning the data to make the changes and pass them to the children, which means that each change should `$emit` a call, which should then be handled by the data owner. Then the data owner will have tom implement loading the data from localstorage on or before mount, and update after each change. As you can see, that will require some extensive changes to your structure, which is why vuex is often preferred.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time spent and the explanation!